# Git Template DearImgui glfw OpenGl

Tags: cmake, compilation, imgui

[My project](https://github.com/Raven-s-Soul/CustomDearImgui), uses DearImgui to make the default GUI to use for different future projects.
I want this template to run on every OS so I'm using CMake, glfw and OpenGL, I have added them as git subprojects.
The project Compiles but some features are missing, I can't drag from the viewport the other windows, like you can do on the Examples inside imgui.
At the moment I have tested on Windows planning soon on Mac OS.
Any kind of help is welcome since this is the 1st time using CMake, and some pieces in CMake are planned to accept more future libs.

I have tried looking at the Docs for CMake Imgui and GLFW.
tried to get some hints and help from ChatGPT and a lot of testing.
Expecting that should work like the example does.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git submodules cant be changed to another branch just by changing
branch = docking
Since only the docking branch has the multi-viewports.